# writing ajax success data in a function without using id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have ajax code as follows which returns data correctly in format i required to be used ina jQuery timepicker function.

Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#consultdate').change(function() {
    consultdate = $('#consultdate').val();
    userid= '<?php echo $user_id;?>';
    cat = '<?php echo $category;?>';
    //alert(consultdate);
    var booked_dates;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'qry/date-time_qry.php',
      dataType : "text",
      data: {consultdate : consultdate, userid : userid, cat : cat },
      success: function(data)
       {
         alert(data);
         booked_dates = data;
       },
      error : function() {
         alert("error while loading data");
       }
     });
  });
</script>
```

The data is returned in format:

```
['12:30 PM','12:45 PM'],['07:30 AM','07:45 AM']
```

Which is to be used in a jQuery timepicker function (`disableTimeRanges`):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input#consulttime').timepicker({
     'timeFormat': 'h:i A',
     'disableTextInput': true,
     'minTime': '<?php echo $consultation_start; ?>',
     'maxTime': '<?php echo $consultation_end; ?>',
     'disableTimeRanges': [
       ['8.30 AM', '8.45 AM'], 
       ['12:15 PM', '12:30 PM'] 
       //document.write= booked_dates; 
      ],
     'step': 15
   });
  });
</script>
```

The data is to be used for `'disableTimeRanges':` which is currently hardcoded for testing.

I tried using `document.write= booked_dates;` without success. 
How can i insert the data values (booked_dates) in the disableTimeRanges without using id?

I am a newbie just learning the skills and hope you forgive me for any oversight on my part.

I tried

Comment: You can initiate `.timepicker()` at `success` callback of `$.ajax()` call, set `data` at `disableTimeRanges` property of the method

Comment: @guest271314 Sorry..i could not get you.

Comment: `success:function(data){$('input#consulttime').timepicker({
'disableTimeRanges':data});}`. Are you trying to call `.timepicker()` at each `change` event of `#consultdate` element or only once?

Comment: @guest271314 I am trying to call .timepicker() at each change event.

Comment: Would that cause multiple events to be attached and dispatched to the same element? Is `data` a string or a JavaScript array?

Comment: @guest271314If i place timepicker inside ajax success call it will display only on consultdate event change. Even inside the ahax success cal the disabled dates were not working.

Comment: @Pamela Can you create a stacksnippets, jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net or plnkr https://plnkr.co to demonstrate?

Comment: @guest271314 
http://jsfiddle.net/grahampcharles/s9bYA/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure your PHP is returning a valid JSON result to the Ajax call. Something like this:

```
[["8.30 AM", "8.45 AM"], ["12:15 PM", "12:30 PM"]]
```

You need the outer brackets to make it an array, and you need to use double quotes instead of single ones.

Then, call `.timepicker()` in the Ajax `success` function of to set the `disableTimeRanges` property. Use `JSON.parse()` function to convert the PHP JSON string into a JSON object:

```
success:function(data) {
    $('input#consulttime').timepicker({'disableTimeRanges':JSON.parse(data)});
  }
}
```

Note: This is based on guest271314's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47118849/3215948) and you can refer to the discussion there for more details.

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery.ajax()` `success` function returns results asynchronously. Call `.timepicker()` at `success` callback of `$.ajax()` to set `disableTimeRanges` property of `.timepicker()` instance. You can include logic within `success` function if `.timepicker()` is only required to be called once at `#consultdate` `change` event. It is not clear if `input#consulttime` is a dynamic created element, relevant to

> without using id

portion of Question

```
success:function(data) {
  // if `data` should be set only once
  // if (!$('input#consulttime').data("set")) {
    $('input#consulttime')
  //  .data("set", true)
    .timepicker({ 'disableTimeRanges':data});
  // }
}
```

Comment: It does not seem to work for me somehow. maybe i am doing something wrong ir the format of the data. In timepicker it should be in format:
'disableTimeRanges': [
['8.30 AM', '8.45 AM'], 
['12:15 PM', '12:30 PM'] 
],

Comment: dataType : "text", Sorry..I am a complete beginner and may miss some valid things.

Comment: The `disableTimeRanges` property expects an array, yes? What does `console.log(data)` log?

Comment: Response is ['12:30 PM','12:45 PM'],['07:30 AM','07:45 AM']

Comment: What does `console.log(JSON.parse(data))` log?

Comment: It is not in JSON format. In php file i just echoed it. No json_encode.
echo $prebooked_time_UTC = $consult_time_UTC ;

Comment: alert(data); is ['12:30 PM','12:45 PM'],['07:30 AM','07:45 AM']

Comment: What does `JSON.parse("[" + data + "]")` log?

Comment: Add extra brackets to the PHP response, so it becomes `[['8.30 AM', '8.45 AM'], ['12:15 PM', '12:30 PM']]`. Then change the code by @guest271314 to `.timepicker({ 'disableTimeRanges':JSON.parse(data)});`.

Comment: @Racil Hilan I will try that.

Comment: @guest271314 Now data is in format : [['12:30 PM','12:45 PM'],['07:30 AM','07:45 AM']],

 and i tried 
$('input#consulttime').timepicker({ 'disableTimeRanges':JSON.parse(data)});

But it is displaying all times. Not disabling the timing. Not working either.

Comment: @Racil Hilan Not working with new format too..please see reply above.

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data

Comment: Yeah, this is not a valid JSON format. Try the new format with @guest271314 answer (without adding `JSON.parse`).

Comment: @Racil Hilan Yes i tried that too. 
$('input#consulttime').timepicker({ 'disableTimeRanges':data});

b.disableTimeRanges.sort is not a function

Comment: @guest271314 b.disableTimeRanges.sort is not a function

Comment: Similar issue at github for the plugin:
https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker/issues/397

Comment: @Racil Hilan I tried using: 
var disableTimeRanges = new Array();
success: function(disableTimeRanges)
{
alert(disableTimeRanges);
$('input#consulttime').timepicker({ 'disableTimeRanges':disableTimeRanges});
},

No change.

Comment: Of course that won't work. OK, just for testing, try this: `$('input#consulttime').timepicker({ 'disableTimeRanges':[['8.30 AM', '8.45 AM'], ['12:15 PM', '12:30 PM']]});`.

Comment: Yeah, that's not a JSON format. Try this `$('input#consulttime').timepicker({ 'disableTimeRanges':eval(data)}); }`. Using `eval()` is dangerous, but it should work.

Comment: @Racil Hilan It is not working. How can i make it properly formatted json data ??

Comment: Times values cannot be JSON keys, so you cannot make it into valid JSON. So `eval()` didn't work? Are you sure your PHP is returning the correct format? Try `$('input#consulttime').timepicker({ 'disableTimeRanges':eval("[['8.30 AM', '8.45 AM'], ['12:15 PM', '12:30 PM']]")});`. If it works, then check and fix your PHP. It must return `[['8.30 AM', '8.45 AM'], ['12:15 PM', '12:30 PM']]`.

Comment: b.disableTimeRanges.sort is not a function is the issue

Comment: That last one was not exactly hardcoded. It used `eval()` to convert the string to an array. Check and fix your PHP to return `[['8.30 AM', '8.45 AM'], ['12:15 PM', '12:30 PM']]` and test it again with `$('input#consulttime').timepicker({ 'disableTimeRanges':eval(data)});`.

Comment: And if you want to convert the format to JSON like you asked earlier, replace the single quotes with double ones like this: `[["8.30 AM", "8.45 AM"], ["12:15 PM", "12:30 PM"]]`. This now will work with `$('input#consulttime').timepicker({ 'disableTimeRanges':JSON.parse(data)});` which is much safer than `eval()`.

Comment: php output is [['12:30 PM','12:45 PM'],['07:30 AM','07:45 AM']]
I will try double quotes.

Comment: @Racil Hilan Thank you so much for your patience. Thanking you once again!!! With lots of love.

Comment: You're welcome. So did the double quotes work with `JSON.parse()`? Just so other readers can benefit. It's hard for the others to follow all these comments, so I can post it in a separate answer.

Comment: @Racil Hilan Yes..Double quotes worked. You can post the answer and i will select it as the solution. Thanking you once again for your patience.

Comment: @Racil Hilan one issue is it seems if we select another date, it seems to show disabled dates of a previous select. Maybe due to cache. cache: false, does not seem to work

Comment: Yes, it is recommended to disable the Ajax cache and it should work. You can test it using `console.log(data)` to see if the value is changing. Perhaps you issue is something else. Try to clear the `disableTimeRanges` first. So maybe `$('input#consulttime').timepicker({ 'disableTimeRanges':[]});` then `$('input#consulttime').timepicker({ 'disableTimeRanges':JSON.parse(data)});`.

Answer (score 1):

I think what @guest271314 means is this :

```
$('#consultdate').change(function() {
    consultdate = $('#consultdate').val();
    userid= '<?php echo $user_id;?>';
    cat = '<?php echo $category;?>';
    //alert(consultdate);
    var booked_dates;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'qry/date-time_qry.php',
        dataType : "text",
        data: { consultdate : consultdate, userid : userid, cat : cat },
        success: function(data) {


            $('input#consulttime').timepicker({
                'timeFormat': 'h:i A',
                'disableTextInput': true,
                'minTime': '<?php echo $consultation_start; ?>',
                'maxTime': '<?php echo $consultation_end; ?>',
                'disableTimeRanges': [
                    ['8.30 AM', '8.45 AM'], 
                    ['12:15 PM', '12:30 PM'],
                    data
                ],
                'step': 15
            });



        },
        error : function() {
            alert("error while loading data");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Not working as timepicker was inside $(document).ready(function(){

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#booking_form").validationEngine('attach', {promptPosition : "topRight:-100,-1", scroll: false});
TIMEPICKER